# Escape column for use in LIKE expression

Tags: mysql, escaping

My server can be used as a file storage. The files cannot be accessed directly where they are stored, but a url where each file can be downloaded is stored in a database.

When I receive a request, I want to check whether it matches a file's url. The url does not have to exactly match the file's url, but can contain additional information at the end. Therefore I must run a `LIKE` query in order to find any matching files:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE '<request-url>' LIKE CONCAT(`url`, '%')
```

This kind of works, but it produces false positives. If for example a file's url is `/file/my_file.pdf`, urls like `/file/my1file.pdf` can be used to access the file, since `_` is a wildcard in `LIKE`.

How can I escape the column `url` so that it can be reliably used in `LIKE` expressions?

Bonus question: What if I needed to use a `REGEXP` expression instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `_` and `%` with `\_` and `\%` to escape them.

```
LIKE CONCAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(url, '_', '\\_'), '%', '\\%'), '%')
```

Another option is to not use `LIKE`

```
WHERE LOCATE(url, '<request-url>') = 1
```

Comment: If the OP is looking for column `url` to be a prefix of the input request, which is what his SQL is suggesting (the language is a bit ambiguous -- see my answer), then you would want ` WHERE LOCATE('<request-url>', url) = 0`

Comment: I think mine is correct. The syntax is `LOCATE(substring, fullstring)`

Comment: No problem, I have trouble remembering the order of arguments to MySQL functions as well. Usually the argument that's likely to be a column is first, so it would be more consistent for it to be as you say.

Comment: That sort of renders my answer superfluous.

Comment: Nice @Barmar! Suppose I went with the `REPLACE` solution, wouldn't I have to escape already-existing `\\` as well?

Comment: @MagnarMyrtveit Yes, although that's unlikely to be in a URL